# Dataloader upload is changing the content

Tags: data-loader

I am trying to insert data into custom object using dataloader tool. But string is getting modified post insert.

Expected string: Paiement rejeté

Converted string: Paiement rejetÃ©

On the other hand, if I use workbench to insert the data, string does not change and remains as expected. As we have larger data to upload, we are using dataloader.

Why does dataloader changes the string? How can we make sure strings does not get changed? Any insight will be helpful.

[image: Upsert screen shot]

Comment: What is the character encoding you're using for the CSV file you're giving to DataLoader? Salesforce (and DataLoader too, I believe) uses UTF-8, so if you're using some other encoding, that could be the issue.

Comment: Hi @DerekF , CSV file encoding is in UTF-8 (while saving the csv, encoding can be provided as UTF-8). but I think the characters are unicode. ie Character é => (UTF-8 Text -> Ã©) (UTF-8 Hex -> \xc3\xa9). We see all Latin-1 are garbled while inserting via dataloader https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block). Is there any way to insert with Latin-1 using dataloader.

Comment: @DerekF, There is an option in dataloader settings, "Read all CSVs with UTF-8 encoding" solves the problem. Thanks for help.